# Oracle select inside insert

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert a row in my table but I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTATION ('NAME', 'VALUE', 'QUERY', 'INSERTDATE') 
 values ('PLATFORM_NAME',
         SELECT PLATFORM_NAME FROM V$DATABASE,
         'SELECT PLATFORM_NAME FROM V$DATABASE',
         SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VALUES can only be used in conjunction with literal values and not with Select statement. However, literal values can be used in a subquery like this:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENTATION (NAME, VALUE, QUERY, INSERTDATE) 
     SELECT 'PLATFORM_NAME', PLATFORM_NAME, 'SELECT PLATFORM_NAME FROM V$DATABASE', SYSDATE 
     FROM V$DATABASE
```